# User list for pubnub-chat objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, chat, pubnub

I have application where pubnub chat feature is been used.
I want to perform below feature

```
1)register / login user in pubnub programatically for chat
2)Get list of the all the users
3)Make friend and send 1st message to the user
```

I am aware about how to create the channel. I had created channel by  below code :

```
    PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:@"pub-c-XXXXXXXXXXXX-a2bf-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"subscribeKey:@"sub-c-XXXXXXXXXXXX-02d0-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"];
        self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
        //[self.client addListener:self];
        [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"my_channel"] withPresence:YES];


I get the channel architecture by : http://pubnub.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/03/05/Inbound-Channel-Pattern.html
But how do i get the list of the users and their channel and send the message.


I  also found this : https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/presence-sdk-v4
but this only show the friends status. whether they are online / offline by 

    Join
    leave 
    timeout

Please advice and help
```

Code to find the list of the users are below but still is show the ZERO users:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:@"pub-c-XXXXXXXXXXXX-a2bf-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"subscribeKey:@"sub-c-XXXXXXXXXXXX-02d0-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"];
        self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
        //Subscription process results arrive to listener which should adopt to PNObjectEventListener protocol and registered using:
        [self.client addListener:self];

        //Listeners callbacks:
        [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"XXX"] withPresence:YES];
        configuration.uuid = @"XXX";
        [self.client hereNowForChannel:@"XXX" withVerbosity:PNHereNowState
                            completion:^(PNPresenceChannelHereNowResult *result,
                                         PNErrorStatus *status) {

                                // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
                                if (!status.isError) {
                                    NSLog(@"list of users %@", result.data.uuids);
                                    NSLog(@"list of result.data.occupancy %@", result.data.occupancy);

                                    //   result.data.uuids - dictionary with active subscriber. Each entry will have next
                                    //                       fields: "uuid" - identifier and "state" if it has been provided.
                                    //   result.data.occupancy - total number of active subscribers.
                                }
                                // Request processing failed.
                                else {
                                    NSLog(@"FAIL");
                                    // Handle presence audit error. Check 'category' property to find
                                    // out possible issue because of which request did fail.
                                    //
                                    // Request can be resent using: [status retry];
                                }
                            }];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Here Now with State

You need to call `hereNowForChannel` with `withVerbosity:PNHereNowState` to get the user's state along with all the subscribed users.

The [Objective-C SDK API Reference Docs for `hereNowForChannel`](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/api-reference-sdk-v4#here_now_example) has more details.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had try to execute by code in simulate. 1) I subscribe with the channel : XXX  and execute the code it gives me the list of result.data.uuids = 0 2)I subscribe with the channel : YYY and execute the code it gives me the list of result.data.uuids = 0. Do i must have to execute the code in the device ? does this count only give me the users which are in PRESENCE mode ? Please explain

Comment: Do you have Presence enabled for your keys in your PubNub Account Dashboard?

Comment: [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"XXX"] withPresence:YES]; and    [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"YYY"] withPresence:YES]; :- I had added this line in the code  Also subscribekey and public key will always be unique right for the complete project ?

Comment: Presence addon in your PubNub account must be enabled.  https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/644/how-do-i-enable-add-on-features-for-my-keys Did you do this for you keys?

Comment: [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"XXX"] withPresence:YES]; and [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"YYY"] withPresence:YES]; :- i had added these line in the code. Also Presence:YES in enable in the dashboard and Dashboard is showing the 2devices for the same key. So the two device means there will be two channels but "herenowforchannel" shows 0 count

Comment: I had send the key and code to them. I am able to get the occupancy count and list of UDID. But i am not sure whether it is other users or same user. i execute the code again and again and the count of occupancy get increase now

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, if you always set the UUID to @"XXX" you will only ever have 1 user. The Presence add-on for PubNub uses the UUID property to track active users on a channel, and if you only use 1 UUID PubNub will treat every client as the same client.

Here is our knowledge base article on setting the UUID
https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/138/how-do-i-set-the-uuid

Also, the iOS PubNub SDK will create and reuse the UUID automatically. This is a new feature as of the 4.2 sdk.
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/api-reference-sdk-v4#uuid_example_2

Comment: This means we always have to save the UUID in the device local storage and instead of assigning the UUID every time ?

Comment: But how can i get the different UUID and get the list of all the other UUID and the name of the channel ? by using the "hereNowForChannel" i am not getting any list of UUID.