# Get list of online users PubNub always nil Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pubnub

My question is same of [User list for pubnub-chat objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692906/user-list-for-pubnub-chat-objective-c) but it seem has no helpful answers.

> 1. I registed client with Pub & Sub key with Presence = YES
> 2. I subsrcibed to "My channel" and could send msg to it
> 3. I used debug console in PubNub admin to create 2 others clients, I could send msg together
> 4. I enable Presence in Admin (http://prntscr.com/iyv7b1)
> 5. I get list user that subscribe "My channel" by function:

```
[client hereNowForChannel:@"My channel" withVerbosity:PNHereNowState completion:^(PNPresenceChannelHereNowResult *result, PNErrorStatus *status)
 {
     if (!status) {

     }
     else {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Couldn't get list of user." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];

         [alert show];
     }
 }];
```

I tried to change

```
PNHereNowState -> PNHereNowUUID -> PNHereNowOccupancy
```

But my result is always NIL.

Anybode help me, pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for my question, hope it helps for who need

```
[client hereNowForChannel:client.globalChannel withCompletion:^(PNPresenceChannelHereNowResult *result, PNErrorStatus *status)
 {
     if (!status) {
         PNPresenceChannelHereNowData *data = result.data;
         if (data) {
             NSArray *list = [data uuids];

         }
     }
     else {

     }
 }];
```

The property **data**, it won't be set value if has no access to it yet, so I did call **PNPresenceChannelHereNowData *data = result.data;** and it had data.